# Starting a process in Python and retrieving its window ID

Tags: python, linux

Let's say I run:

```
import subprocess;
P = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal');
```

I then get an object `P` of the class `Popen`:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xb72a9d0c>
```

How can I then retrieve the `window identity` of this subprocess?

Ultimately, I would like to manipulate the geometrical properties of the window spawned by the subprocess using [wmctrl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl), but for this I need something known as the `windows identity` of the window (see the documentation of [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl))

To provide more context to the question, `wmctrl -l` outputs a list of windows running on the GNOME desktop, where the first column shows the `window identity` of each window. This is a hexadecimal number that I have noticed is **different** from the one included in the output reported by Popen above.

I checked the [Popen documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) but I am not sure how to proceed from this point.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to get the window ID is to use `wmctrl -lp` which will include the PID of the processes. Find the one that matches the [`Popen.pid`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid) of your subprocess and you'll find the window id of the process.

Comment: `wmctrl -lp` returns a list of windows and their `PIDs`, but several of these windows (terminals, as in the example above) are listed under the same `PID`. 

How can tell which one is which? Does a `Popen` object hold any other identifier that allows me to identify the process univocally?

Comment: @AmV: If gnome-terminal runs all its instances under the same PID, you may not be able to use this method at all. Is the command line column useful?

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using external shell utility then [`xdotool`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xdotool&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&format=html) can be used:

`xdotool search --any --pid 1234`